# how can i implement the horrizontal scrolling for the inner context of the HTML5 svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

i have the series of rectangle boxes in to the svg, exceeding from SVG tag's Width for the same i want to implement the scrolling to its inner matter with external button such that it would scroll from initial to its max inner width of content.
i reffed the logic from the canvas code here in : 
http://jsfiddle.net/CQPeU/
    from this code:

```
window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    var evt = e || event;
    if (dragging) {
        var delta = evt.offsetX - lastX;
        translated += delta;
        ctx.translate(delta, 0); // translate the context.
        lastX = evt.offsetX;
        draw(); // redraw
    }
}
```

i tried the same with changing the attribute transoform:translate(x,0) with varing the x value for horizontal scrolling.but couldn't find exact implementation.

Comment: Do you have an example jsfiddle with the rectangles that aren't scrolling, for people to have a play with ?

Answer (score 0):

SVG behaves like it's own little html document, and has a funky attribute called viewBox that may help you.

Let's assume you have an svg element with some stuff inside that measures 200x200. If you render it with these viewBox properties, it will display as you'd expect.

```
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0,0,200,200"></svg>
```

The attribute values refer to:

```
minx, miny, width, height
```

Where minx is the x position in your svg document at the left of the rendered area, and miny is the y position of your svg document at the top of the rendered area.

If you keep the width and height at 200, changing these minx and miny values essentially shifts the top left position of a 200x200 viewable window across all of your svg content.

Modifying the width and height gives you the ability to zoom in or out on a portion of the svg, though this might not apply to your example.. still kinda handy to know :)

For your example, try incrementing or decrementing your minx and miny values in the viewBox attribute based on the mouse drag movements you are getting in your event listener.

Comment: Thanks for "viewBox", its working but now the question is how can i insert the scrolling animation effect something like easing or with simple timing effect...

Comment: also i wonder that for the positive value of x svg is moving left rather than right..

Comment: Seems counterintuitive, but if you think about manually shifting the view window to the left (negative), it makes sense that the vector content would move further right. You're basically 'revealing' more of the left side of the svg.

Comment: but the methods seems to be very slow in all the browsers and i could not able to check it with changing time factors also dont give that smooth scrolling.